# Bootstrap v3 make exports empty css files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, makefile

I'm trying to preview bootstrap v3, and I've followed the instructions in the README.md, but the two css files that get exported are empty. The steps I took were:

1. Download & unzip the lastest 3.0.0-wip
2. `cd /Workspace/bookstrap-3.0.0-wip/`
3. `npm install`
4. `make`
5. `make bootstrap`

The javascript files export just fine. The fonts are junk (but the "source" files are also junk, so I'm not too concerned about that).

P.S. I opened a question here rather than an issue on github because I think I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a syntax error in bootstraps source which recess silently ignores. commit ced641b has fixed it (and I was able to compile). Lessc reports these errors. I suggest troubleshooting with lessc when encountering this sort of issue:

```
cd bootstrap_parent_dir/
npm install lessc
lessc less/bootstrap.less
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that all the correct dependencies are installed

```
sudo npm install recess connect uglify-js jshint -g
```

Comment: shouldn't `npm install` install the dependencies?